# Android Studio : Send GPS coordinates (lat lon) in a POST request via Foreground Service

Tags: android

I'm developing a small application in Android Studio that would allow me to send GPS coordinates lat/lon to my web server and via a API POST request.
As a first test, I developed a button (in my MainActivity) for sending lat/lon which works very well: a function is responsible for retrieving the GPS coordinates then I call another function to send lat and lon to my API.
I also created a Service for automatic start (a class Service named MyForegroundService). The service start automaticaly when system starts and without user interaction and makes the Web request to my Web API at interval time defined. However, the lat and lon coordinates remain infortunatly at 0.0. It seems the LocationRequest doesn't work as expected in this class.
The problem seems to be in this code :

```
val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            locationResult.lastLocation?.let
```

I have also notified that if i launch my application (MAinActivity) then the LocationRequest work as expected in MyForegroundService even if i close Application (MainActivity), the lat/lon continues to be correctly retrieve via LocationRequest.
Thank you very much in advance if you have any idea of the problem.

MainActivity is :

`fdfd`

Comment: Make sure that you have [the `location` foreground service type](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/fgs-types-required#location).

Comment: Sorry i really like to post all the code but CTRL+K doesn't work. Yes, i have the autorizations in my Manifest (FOREGROUND_SERVICE,FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION,RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED). The lat/lon are good during all the time if a launch just one time the application (MainActivity) and also after if it stop the Application (MainActivity)

Comment: You additionally need to make sure your app is able to get location data when it is in the background: https://developer.android.com/develop/sensors-and-location/location/background